# How many one-one mapping $f:\mathbb{Z}_{15} \to \mathbb{Z}_{15}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many one-one mapping $f:\mathbb{Z}_{15} \to \mathbb{Z}_{15}$?

I think the answer would be $15!$ since every one-one mapping on a finite set is bijective. and number of bijective map from 15 element set to 15 element set is $15!$

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense, but the meaning of "one-one mapping" can depend on the context. Since you used the abstract-algebra tag and $\Bbb Z_{15}$ has some algebraic structure, you might be meant to count only homomorphisms of some kind.

Comment: Yes. It was asked in a exam paper. They doesn't make use of the word homomorphism. This made me confused

Comment: Unless in your course it was **explicitly** stated that "mapping" is to refer only to homomorphisms or some other limited specification, you are correct. And I am highly doubtful that someone would make such a restriction (if they did, they would make it impossible to even mention mappings that did not meet that specification).